# How do I retrieve a value when using the "function" syntax to perform pattern matching?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

**The following line doesn't compile:**

```
| IsNeither  -> sprintf "%i" // ???
```

**Here's the function that this line belongs to:**

```
let run = function

    | IsFizzBuzz -> "Fizz Buzz"
    | IsFizz     -> "Fizz"
    | IsBuzz     -> "Buzz"
    | IsNeither  -> sprintf "%i" // Doesn't compile
```

**Here's the entire program:**
    module Temp

```
let (|IsFizz|IsBuzz|IsFizzBuzz|IsNeither|) = function
    | n when n % 3 = 0 && 
             n % 5 = 0 -> IsFizzBuzz
    | n when n % 3 = 0 -> IsFizz
    | n when n % 5 = 0 -> IsBuzz
    | n ->                IsNeither

let run = function

    | IsFizzBuzz -> "Fizz Buzz"
    | IsFizz     -> "Fizz"
    | IsBuzz     -> "Buzz"
    | IsNeither  -> sprintf "%i" // Doesn't compile

let result = [1..16] |> List.map(run)
```

Can I still extract a value using the "function" syntax on the signature?

Example:

```
let (|IsFizz|IsBuzz|IsFizzBuzz|IsNeither|) = function
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a solution that does not require you to re-define your patterns, by using the `as` keyword:

```
let run = function
    | IsFizzBuzz -> "Fizz Buzz"
    | IsFizz     -> "Fizz"
    | IsBuzz     -> "Buzz"
    | IsNeither as n -> sprintf "%i" n
```

This nicely works across active patterns, matching discriminated union cases, etc. A prominent use case are type checks, where you have matches like `| :? string as s`

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution would be to make the value part of the pattern.

```
let (|IsFizz|IsBuzz|IsFizzBuzz|IsNeither|) = function
    | n when n % 3 = 0 && 
             n % 5 = 0 -> IsFizzBuzz
    | n when n % 3 = 0 -> IsFizz
    | n when n % 5 = 0 -> IsBuzz
    | n                -> IsNeither n

let run = function
    | IsFizzBuzz  -> "Fizz Buzz"
    | IsFizz      -> "Fizz"
    | IsBuzz      -> "Buzz"
    | IsNeither n -> sprintf "%i" n
```

Answer (score 6):

Having a `neither` case indicates that not all values can be partitioned into the "domain" and so a [Partial Active Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns#partial-active-patterns) is probably a better choice.
Associated with the [AND pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#and-pattern) it can simplifies the code (at cost of some changes)

```
// common code extracted and inlined (optional)
let inline isDivisibleBy divisor dividend =
  if dividend % divisor = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
  then Some ()
  else None

let (|Fizz|_|) = isDivisibleBy 3
let (|Buzz|_|) = isDivisibleBy 5

let run = function Fizz & Buzz -> "FizzBuzz"
                 | Fizz        -> "Fizz"
                 | Buzz        -> "Buzz"
                 | x           -> string x

let result = List.map run [1 .. 16]
```

Going down this road one can even get rid of those `Fizz` and `Buzz` function in favor to the a general `IsDivisibleBy`

```
let inline (|IsDivisibleBy|_|) divisor dividend =
  if dividend % divisor = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
  then Some ()
  else None

let run = function IsDivisibleBy 3 & IsDivisibleBy 5 -> "FizzBuzz"
                 | IsDivisibleBy 3                   -> "Fizz"
                 | IsDivisibleBy 5                   -> "Buzz"
                 | x                                 -> string x

let result = List.map run [1 .. 16]
```

Or even that way if you still want those `Fizz` and `Buzz` you can still do

```
let (|Fizz|_|) = (|IsDivisibleBy|_|) 3
let (|Buzz|_|) = (|IsDivisibleBy|_|) 5
```